# Выводится ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

пытаюсь по книге написать игру Skier, но выводится вот такая ошибка:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Skier2.py", line 86, in <module>
    map0 = create_map (20, 29)
NameError: name 'create_map' is not defined
```

Вот код, в котором получается эта ошибка:

```
if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0:
        activeMap = 1
        map0 = create_map (20, 29)
        obstacles = updateObsstacleGroup (map0, map1)
    if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0 :
        activeMap = 0
        for ob in map0:
            ob.location[1] = ob.location [1] -1280
        map_position = map_position - 1280
        map1 = create_map (10, 19)
        obstacles = updateObstaclesGroup (map0, map1)
```

Если кому нужен будет весь код:

```
#First Game!!!!

import pygame, sys, random

skier_images = ["skier_down.png", "skier_right1.png",
                "skier_right2.png", "skier_left2.png",
                "skier_left1.png"]

class SkierClass (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self) :
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        import os
        print (os.getcwd(), os.path.exists("D:\My Games\skier_images\skier_down.png"))
        self.image = pygame.image.load ("D:\My Games\skier_images\skier_down.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect ()
        self.rect.center = [320, 100]
        self.angle = 0

    def turn(self, direction) :
        self.angle = self.angle + direction
        if self.angle < -2:    self.angle = -2
        if self.angle > 2:    self.angle = 2
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.load(skier_images[self.angle])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) *2]
        return speed

    def move (self, speed):
         self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + speed[0]
         if self.rect.centerx < 20: self.rect.centerx = 20
         if self.rect.centerx < 620: self.rect.centerx = 620

class ObsticalsClass (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, type) :
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ (self)
        self.image_file = image_file
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.location = loacation
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = location
        self.type = type
        self.passed = False

        def scroll (self, t_ptr):
            self.rect.centery = self.location[1] - t_ptr

def creat_map(start, end):
    obsticals = pygame.sprite.Group()
    grates = pygame.sprite.Group()
    locations = []
    for i in range (10):
        row = random.randit (start, end)
        col = random.randit (0, 9)
        location = [col * 64 + 20, row * 64 + 20]
        if not (location in locations) :
            locations.append(location)
            type = random.choice(["tree", "flag"])
            if type == "tree": img = "D:\My Games\skier_images\skier_tree.png"
            elif type == "flag":  img = "D:\My Games\skier_images\skier_flag.png"
            obstacle = ObstacleClass (img, location, type)
            obstacles.add(obstacle)
    return obstacles
def animate ():
    screen.fill ([255, 255, 255])
    pygame.display.update (obstacles.draw(screen))
    screen.blit (skier.image, skier.rect)
    screen.blit(score_text, [10 ,10])
    pygame.display.flip()

def updateObstacleGroup (map0, map1):
    obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for ob in map0: obstacles.add (ob)
    for ob in map1: obstacles.add (ob)
    return obstacles

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ([640, 640])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
skier = SkierClass()
speed = [0, 6]
map_position = 0
points = 0
map_position = 0
map0 = create_map (20, 29)
map1 = create_map (10, 19)
activeMap = 0
obstacles = updateObstacleGroup (map0, map1)
font = pygame.font.Font (None, 50)


while True:
    clock.tick (30)
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = skier.turn (-1)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = skier.turn (1)
    skier.move (speed)
    map_position += speed [1]

    if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0:
        activeMap = 1
        map0 = create_map (20, 29)
        obstacles = updateObsstacleGroup (map0, map1)
    if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0 :
        activeMap = 0
        for ob in map0:
            ob.location[1] = ob.location [1] -1280
        map_position = map_position - 1280
        map1 = create_map (10, 19)
        obstacles = updateObstaclesGroup (map0, map1)

for obstacles in obstacles:
    obstacles.scroll (map_position)

hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide (skier, obstacles, False)
if hit:
    if hit [0] .type == "tree" and not hit [0] .passed:
        points - 100
        skier.image = pygame.image.load ("D:\My Games\skier_images\skier_crash.png")
        animate()
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        skier.angle = 0
        speed = [0, 6]
        hit[0] .passed = True
    elif hit [0] .type == "flag" and not hit [0] .passed:
        points += 10
        obstacles.remove (hit[0])


score_text = font.render ("Score: " +str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))
animate ()

pygame.quit()
```

---

В данном коде где должен находиться list?:

```
#Поворачиваем лыжника
    def turn(self, direction):
        self.angle = self.angle + direction
        if self.angle < -2: self.angle = -2
        if self.angle > 2: self.angle = 2
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images('D:\My Games\skier_images\self.angle'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) * 2]
        return speed
```

Пишет, что где-то в строке self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images...), но где?

---

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\Skier.py", line 98, in <module>
    speed = skier.turn(-1)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\Skier.py", line 23, in turn
    self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images('D:\My Games\skier_images\self.angle'))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Вы бы дочитали бы книгу - не надо сразу бросаться на большой и сложный код, сделанный не Вами. Поделайте простые программы, поймите что обозначает вывод при ошибках, поучитесь создавать что-то попроще, но своё...

Comment: И, кстати, в преддверие Вашего третьего вопроса. Либо заменяйте \ в маршрутах на \\, либо используйте `/`, как в Линуксе. Это я про вот этот кусок: `'D:\My Games\skier_images\self.angle'`

Comment: map0 = create_map (20, 29) убери пробел после create_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас название функции написано с ошибкой.

Вместо

```
def creat_map(start, end):
```

должно быть

```
def create_map(start, end):
```

Comment: Изменил, снова ошибка

Comment: Но нашёл другой код, в котором более менее всё понятно.

Comment: И там тоже ошибка

Comment: Хочу с ним проработать

Comment: А так благодарю

Comment: Такая же или другая?

Comment: Посмотри, я вывел

Comment: skier_images и есть список, вы же в самом начале всего кода его именно как список создали. А список нельзя вызвать как функцию, с аргументом в круглых скобках

Comment: То есть там, где skier_images помсле него должны идти [ ] эти скобки?

Comment: Вот не знаю, какая у вас там логика ожидается. Если вам нужно реализовать доступ к элементу привет его номеру - то да, квадратные скобки. Но вы же там не номер, а какой-то путь файла передаете. Я не понимаю, что вы хотели сделать.